# Schedule "Reporting Snapshot" using apex

Tags: apex, reporting, schedule, snapshot

Do you know if there is a way to schedule native SF Snapshots using apex? I want to make a snapshot run daily for 10 days the first month of every quarter. I haven't gotten to figuring out the cron expression for this yet, would like to first know if I can even use it.

Comment: Did you figure out a method for this? I am trying to make a VF page where users can easily schedule multiple snapshots

Comment: Have not yet seen the way to do it..

Comment: hillarious.  here I am 7 years later searching again how to do it, and finding just my own unasnwered question..